# Can't Display proper result with Binary Reader

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stream, binaryreader

i have made two functions using binary streams

first one takes array as an arguement and writes data in file ... code:

```
      public static void BinaryWrite(List<person> People)
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\filestream.txt";

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<People.Count;i++)
                    {
                        bw.Write(People[i].name);
                        bw.Write(People[i].surname);
                        bw.Write(People[i].age);
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

Second one should read the data:

```
  public static void BinaryRead()
    {
        string path = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\filestream.txt";

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < br.BaseStream.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(br.ReadString());
                }

            }
        }
    }

enter code here
```

but when i run the code i get the following exception

**System.IO.EndOfStreamException: 'Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.'**

what can be a problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build the loop by considering `BaseStream.Position`

```
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
{
    while(br.BaseStream.Position < br.BaseStream.Length)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(br.ReadString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well Still getting same exception

Answer (score 1):

`ReadString()` method requires special format in the string, with prefixed of length on the start of each read.

Instead of having a special format you can just read it like so:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
       using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
       {
            while (br.BaseStream.Position < br.BaseStream.Length)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine((char)br.Read());
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Same Expception occured